# How do I verify if my share app link is working in android studio before publshing app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have added a share app button and link to my app made in android studio but I'm not sure if this is the way it should work as I have checked other apps' share options and they tend to give the user an option on where exactly they'd like to share their application, while my link sends the user straight to the app page. I found this method on another thread made on this website but I'm not sure if it works properly as I haven't published my app yet. Can someone verify if this is the most popular method to share apps and if not can someone redirect me to where I can find the best solution for a share app option.

segment of my MainActivity.java code regarding the share method:

```
 @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
   
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_share:
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mydomain.tapp"));
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong `Intent Action` for your requirement. Your requirement is to share your app's PlayStore link with another person. So, you have to use `ACTION_SEND`.

`ACTION_VIEW` is used to display the data to the user.

`ACTION_SEND` is used to deliver some data to someone else.

For example,

```
Intent intent  = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Sharing URL");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mydomain.tapp");
startActivity(intent);
```